# Calling a base class' method

Tags: c#, oop

In c++ I would do

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void stuff()
    {
        //something
    }
};

class B : public A
public:
    virtual void stuff()
    {
        //something2
        A::stuff() //something
    }
};
```

How would I do this in C#?
I've tried

```
public void stuff()
{
    //something2
    A.stuff(); //something
}
```

but that doesn't work

Answer (score 164, accepted):

`base` is the keyword for referencing your superclass in C#. Use:

```
base.stuff();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this as an answer as soon as it lets me :)

Comment: Is this like super.stuff() in Java?

Comment: @pratnala: Yes.

Comment: Was `base` chosen for the sole purpose of being different? Seems like every other language with inheritance calls it `super`...

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: I mean, no clue, but my guess is it's not that different from 'this' vs. 'self' (Python)...

Comment: @Mehrdad - Python predates most (all?) languages which used `this`. Also, `self` is a convention, not a keyword, in Python - your first argument of a method will always be assigned to the instance of the class, no matter what you call it. `self` came from the Smalltalk language.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: *"Python predates most (all?) languages which used this."* Right, so I was asking you why did people use `this` when `self` was already being used? Was it chosen for the sole purpose of being different? Same question you asked. *"Also, self is a convention, not a keyword, in Python."* OK, so what? Your complaint would've been the same whether `base` was a conventional identifier or a keyword.

Comment: Still, your superclass method required to be protected declared :)

Answer (score 10):

Use `base`. Like `base.stuff();`

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to the answer above, base.stuff() works, unless it's the constructor you're trying to call in which case it is called as:

```
class A
{
public:
    public A(){}

};

class B : A
{
    public B() : base()
    {

    }
};
```